# Smooth scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make so when you click on a text i want it to animate to a part of the page further down.
example: https://osynlig.se
click on Case and u can see that it animates down to that part of the page.

on my website. When i click on home,Info,contact us i want it to animate to the part of the page where those things are and i dont know how to do that :(

http://pixelatedore.zapto.org/ to see that code go to my website and do ctrl+u

i dont know how to paste in code here :3.

If you could send a link to a website that explains or if you know and write in the comments. that would be higly appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".anchor").click(function(e){
      $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 1000);
   });
});
```

```css
#top{background-color:red;}
#middle{background-color:yellow;}
#bottom{background-color:green;}
div.block{height:400px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toppage"></div>
<a class="anchor" href="#top"> 
        <div class="arrow-down-light-blue">top</div>
    </a>


    <a class="anchor" href="#middle">
        <div class="arrow-down-light-blue">middle</div>
   

    <a class="anchor" href="#bottom">
        <div class="arrow-down-light-blue">bottom</div>
    </a>

<div class="block" id="top">The top
  <a class="anchor" href="#toppage"> Back to top</a>
      </div>
<div class="block" id="middle">The middle
      <a class="anchor" href="#toppage"> Back to top</a>
      </div>
<div  class="block" id="bottom">The bottom
      <a class="anchor" href="#toppage"> Back to top</a>
      </div>
```

Comment: works only in chrome. in IE it jumps to top before scrolling, in ff it just jumps without scrolling.

Comment: after I saw your comment I tested on Chrome,IE and Opera, worked fine on all 3, I don't have FF to test it on. Sure there is other ways to do it if needed. The fact that it's jumping straight to the section in FF suggests that jquery isn't loading for some reason...